# Excel Inserting data in between row field

Tags: excel, vba

i have created a sample table in below which is quite similar to simulate the situations i am facing. i need an excel vba code or can it be done using formula?
**Current Table**

```
column1   | 
------------
  A       | 
  A       | 
  A       |   
  B       |   
  B       | 
  C       | 
  D       |   
  D       |
```

**Outcome desired**

```
column1   | 
------------
  A       | 
  go      |
  A       |
  go      | 
  A       |
  go      |   
  B       |
  go      |   
  B       |
  go      | 
  C       |
  go      | 
  D       |
  go      |   
  D       |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formula approach

```
=IF(ISODD(ROW(A1)),INDEX(A:A,CEILING(ROW(A1)/2,1)),"go")
```

Copy down as far as required. You can then copy the resulting column and paste it over itself with Paste Special > Values, then delete the original column.

**Explanation**: Read the formula from the inside out. `Row(A1)` will return the number 1. Divided by 2, returns 0.5, use Ceiling to return the next full integer, which is 1. Copied down to row 3, for example, `Row(A3)` returns 3, divide by 2 = 1.5, round up to next full integer returns 2.

So, in row 1 the formula evaluates to `Index(A:A,1)`, which means "return the first cell in the range A:A". In row 3 the formula evaluates to `Index(A:A,2)` which means - You got it! In row 5, we will get `Index(A:A,3)` and so on.

Run the formula through the Evaluate Formula tool on the Formulas ribbon to see these actions performed step by step.

Comment: This is exactly what i want, thank you so much, can you explain to me this part INDEX(A:A,CEILING(ROW(A1)/2,1))?

Comment: I added an explanation.